# Redirect not able to send response

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using redirect in Django to send the user to another page but it is not able to do so.

views.py

```
def func1(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'login/login/login.html')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            return redirect('base:func2')
        return render(request, 'base/home/index.html')


def func2(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'login/login/login.html')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            ....
            return render(request,
                          'bla_bla_bla.html',
                          {'location': location})
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            print('COntrol is here')
            some_details_form = SomeDetailsForm()
            return render(request, 'some_url/index.html',
                          {'some_details_form': some_details_form})
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'base'
url(r'^another_url/$', views.func2, name='func2'),
url(r'^some_url/$', views.func1, name='func1'),
```

base/home/index.html

```
<div class="button" onclick="clicked_it()">
    <span id="forward"> Go Further   </span>
</div>
```

index.js

`function clicked_it()
{
    $.post( "/base/some_url/");
};`

So the control does go to **func2** since I can see the print statement output ***COntrol is here*** but I don't see that the func2 is able to render the page in the return statement. Where is the control getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using Ajax is that it overrides the browser navigation handling. If you want your Ajax to redirect, you need to do it in js - or, don't use Ajax at all.

Comment: Could you be little more specific about what to do, since I'm new to web development and have little or no knowledge of JS

Comment: First explain why you have that `clicked_it()` function at all, rather than a normal link or button.

Comment: I'm using this to send data to the backend which the user would enter on the page.

Comment: That didn't answer the question. Why don't you use a normal form? Why Ajax?

Comment: Well I can do that also. Nothing specific

Comment: So, do that. Then your redirect will just work. Later, when you're more confident in web development, and if you need it, you can implement it using Ajax.

Comment: Ok. Thanks , I will implement simple post to my logic. But can you please let me know what is the problem I fell into?

Answer (score 0):

redirect either needs the relative or absolute url that you need to redirect to. 
You need to use django reverse url resolver

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse 

def func1(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'login/login/login.html')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            return redirect(reverse('base:func2'))
        return render(request, 'base/home/index.html')
```

Comment: Nope .. It still is not able to redirect